# Using RStudio to make figures side by side horizontally

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am a current undergraduate student working on some data analysis for my first small research project. I am making a figure to represent Odds ratios and I want the figures to be horizontal instead of stacking vertically so that they fit on my poster better. Can anyone help me with this? I was not sure if there was a command that could make them line up horizontally without losing any of the correct labels on the right axes

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `par(mfrow = )`

```
data(mtcars)
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1


par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(x = mtcars$mpg, y = mtcars$disp, type= 'p')
plot(x = mtcars$mpg, y = mtcars$hp, type= 'p')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSAxY.png)

This, however, does not work with `ggplot`. For `ggplot`, you can transform the data to its long version, and then plot using `facet_grid`:

```
mtcars_long <- mtcars %>%
   select(mpg, disp, hp) %>%
   gather(key = "variable", value = "value", -mpg)

ggplot(data = mtcars_long, aes(x = mpg, y = value)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_grid(~ variable)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zpHs.png)

HTH